# Asset is renamed from .tar.gz to .tar after packing apk

Tags: android, assets, aapt

My android app has an `tar.gz` asset, but whenever I build the apk, the asset is renamed to `tar` extension. I've confirmed such 'issue' in two ways:

- I wrote code to list all assets and realized the asset extension changed to just `tar` instead of `tar.gz` I would expect. `context.getAssets().list("my_tar_gz_files");`
- After compile apk, I unpacked it and looked into **assets/my_tar_gz_files** folder. Actually my `tar.gz` file was now named just as `tar`.

How can I build my apk in such way it will find the original `tar.gz` instead of the `tar`?

I can pass through it looking for a `tar` file instead a `tar.gz`, but it is really bad for maintainability purposes.

Building with both Eclipse/ADT or ant presents the same behavior. And please, do not ask me to double check the file name I'm packing into the apk.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to maintain the gzip? I imagine the incompatibility comes when the apk is being zip aligned, possibly removing the zip compression of your asset, or possibly just truncating naming and rendering the asset unreadable. Either way, if you can get away with allowing a slightly larger file, I would just archive the asset as a tar, without gzipping the file as well.

Comment: @ChrisM My app is receiving those gzip files from a third-party partner. Also the files will be used as input to a larger system which is already in production, and it expects a tar.gz as input. Just change to `tar` is nor an option right now. My way out of this issue might be put the gzip into res/raw.